# Big memory leak if in AngularJs we use $compile in createdRow() in jquery datatables

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I've noticed that if we use angularJs $compile on a datatable createdRow()
When reload reloadData grow numbre of detached watchers and unattended DOM stuff

Even when use pagination is growing this becouse in paginations datatable execute createdRow()

Is it possible destroy previous $compiles Rows before enter in createdRows and avoid this Big memory leak?

We use angularJs $compile because We whant render the datatable rows with some interaction as buttons ng-click and we want this interaction with functions in the $scope of the controller Wehre the datatable is created.

Sorry my English

Please if you know an alternative idea or a solution let me know.

Thank you in advance for your help and support.

EDITED FOR MORE INFO:
Thanks scipper for help.

I add this test about the problem, a lot of hours and still can't free that memory leak:

Starting with this example:

```
http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/rerender
```

If rerender a lot of times this example and no memory leaks

** But in my version I use reloadData like this: **

```
$scope.dtOptionsMyTable = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
.withOption('ajax', function(){........})
.withOption('createdRow', function (row, data, dataIndex) {
$compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
})
```

And I do not know why we have an incresing use of leak memory. Garbage colector do not remove all.

How can I remove all these elements in memory?

**I try this in every reload:**

instanceTable.DataTable.clear();

Even we try to compile in another child object intead of this

```
$compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
```

**I try this in every reload**

var newCreatedChildScope= $scope.$new(false);
$compile(angular.element(row).contents())(newCreatedChildScope);

and then in every reload destroy the childscope this way

```
newCreatedChildScope.$destroy();
newCreatedChildScope=null;
```

Still a lot of memory leaks.

Are there a way using a instance.DataTable reference destroy a lot more about the table before reload data? I think this could be the solution

Thanks

Comment: It seems my app has the same issue. How do you detect memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, what problem you are describing regarding memory leaks, but I think the answer to your question **Is it possible destroy previous $compiles Rows** is, YES. The moment, they are removed from the DOM, they are destoyed.

If you still experience memory leaks, try to share more information with us.

Comment: I edit the question adding more info i find out about the code I`m trying to clean memory leaks.  Please, could you write an example how destroy compiles ROWS, how woud you do it.